# undefined symbol: gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_conjugate_fr when trying to install topicmodels in R

Tags: r, gsl, topicmodels

I've been trying to install the `topicmodels` package in R for quite a few minutes. I've read many tutorials and installed the gsl package, but I'm still getting this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘topicmodels’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 impossível carregar objeto compartilhado '/home/sillas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/topicmodels/libs/topicmodels.so':
  /home/sillas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/topicmodels/libs/topicmodels.so: undefined symbol: gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_conjugate_fr
Erro: loading failed
Execução interrompida
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/sillas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/topicmodels’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘topicmodels’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: maybe this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025379/error-installing-topicmodels-in-r-ubuntu

Comment: I've already read that one. It didn't work. It seems that I have a broken package on Linux.